# UITableViewController vs UITableView in UIViewController Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

When I parse into a `UITableView` the data loads quickly and right away. But, when using a `UITableView` within a `UIViewController`, the table view takes a very long time to display on its own, but will load quickly if the table view is swiped. Why is this?

[image: img1]

It works with  ViewConvtrollerf: UITableViewController UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

But I need to fit that in a UIViewController.....

Comment: There's not enough info here to help you. How are you adding the `UITableView` to the `UIViewController`? Or is this question about the data appearing within the `UITableView`? Do you use different methods / techniques for loading data between the two methods?

Comment: This is clearly about two different methods. The parse into the UITableView works immediately. That means the UITableView prototype etc....But when putting parse into UITableView embedded within a UIViewController it does not load unless swiped.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ew72k.png

Comment: check that image, the one to the right works quick, the one to the left does not.

Comment: A screenshot from IB is not relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to reload your table view's data on viewWillAppear. This way you'll have the tableView loads fast.

Objective-C:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
  [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Swift:

```
  override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
  }
```

Comment: @JamesShelton What do you mean by "swipe"?

Comment: it is still not loading quickly, requires touch, compared to the automatic loading that takes place when it is a UItableview

Comment: by swipe i mean drug the table as if I were scrolling through it

Comment: So you're saying that your table will only load if you touch/swipe it?

Comment: Link your delegate/datasource in Storyboard

Comment: How are you getting the data of your table?

Comment: NSMutableDictionary = self.tableData[indexPath.row] as NSMutableDictionary

Comment: sometimes it loads immediately, sometimes it requires a swipe. very bizarre